# window.addEventListener No carga las 2 funciones

Tags: javascript

Buen dia y gracias de antemano por el apoyo.
Tengo 2 elementos "Select" en una ventana modal.
existen  dos funciones para que se cargen lo elementos al modal.
pero solo me carga uno de los 2.  como puedo hacer load de las dos funciones y que las mantenga.

tambien intente con el "document.addEventListener"

Saludos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  ftnClientes();
  ftnCategorias();
});


function ftnClientes(){
var ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Clientes/getSelectClientes';
var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
request.open("GET",ajaxUrl,true);
request.send();

request.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(request.readyState == 4 & request.status == 200){
        document.querySelector('#listCliente').innerHTML = request.responseText;
        document.querySelector('#listCliente').value = 0;
        $('#listCliente').selectpicker('render');

    }
}


}
function ftnCategorias(){
 var ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Categorias/getSelectCategorias';
var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
request.open("GET",ajaxUrl,true);
request.send();

request.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(request.readyState == 4 & request.status == 200){
        document.querySelector('#listCategoria').innerHTML = request.responseText;
        document.querySelector('#listCategoria').value = 0;
        $('#listCategoria').selectpicker('render');

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Cuál es tu pregunta? El código que compartes funciona de maravilla. Puedo ver ambos alerts.

Comment: Disculpa ,  tal vez no me explicque bien.
Cuando carga el modal.  en los dos campos select solo  trae la lista de  de una funcion ya sea cliente o categorias. 
en otras palabra no lo gro hacer que carge las dos  funciones al mismo tiempo.
(Para efectos de postear la pregunta  sustitui el codigo por "alert("Lista de Categorias") y entiendo que no podria poner dos alertas. al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Necesitas dar más detalles. Cómo sabes que ambas peticiones funcionan? Se dispara el código para ambas? Cómo sabes si ambas peticiones traen datos? los puedes ver en la pestaña "network" de las herramientas de desarrollador? Tu back end está devolviendo datos? si usas ajax, ya hiciste un console log en el `success/done`? Cómo sabes si tus métodos en realidad funcionan?

Comment: Cuando  dejo una sola peticion  en esta parte.
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  ftnClientes();
  ftnCategorias();
});

si me muestra lso datos correctamente no importa cual deje.
 incluire mi codigo  completo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404380/why-doesnt-document-addeventlistenerload-function-work-in-a-greasemonkey-s